# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 2 of

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am facing problems with reaching details activity from main listview. I am getting empty Details Activity. The tutorial that was used for this operations is following: [Tutorial](https://androidjson.com/android-php-insert-display-select-update-delete/#comment-799).

Can you help guys, i have a deadline tomorrow.

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            try
            {
                if(FinalJSonObject != null)
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject;
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonObject);



                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing Student Name, Phone Number, Class into Variables.
                            NameHolder = jsonObject.getString("property_name").toString() ;
                            NumberHolder = jsonObject.getString("price").toString() ;
                            ClassHolder = jsonObject.getString("description").toString() ;

                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Error in debugger:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 2 of   
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
W/System.err:     at com.example.said.populate.DetailsActivity$GetHttpResponse.doInBackground(DetailsActivity.java:129)
W/System.err:     at com.example.said.populate.DetailsActivity$GetHttpResponse.doInBackground(DetailsActivity.java:104)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: do you have teamviewer? actually problem cant be solved with given code snippet or elaborate it more

Comment: @SurinderSinghBindra can you suggest other tutorials that does the same function?

Comment: plz add value of FinalJsonObject to log cat and show here as well.

Comment: @sontruongit How to that? what is log cat?

Comment: @Natlus Log.i("TAG", FinalJsonObject.toString());

Comment: @Natlus this is a very basic thing. you can share your Code so I can check or either send me the FinalJSonObject Value